# Backuppc | Got fatal error during xfer (aborted by signal=PIPE)

Tags: ssh, backup, pipe, backuppc

I am running backuppc version 3.3.1 on an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, I try to backup several Linux servers, almost Debian, ubuntu or proxmox hosts.

My issue is that when I run the Full/Incermental backup from webUI I got the message:

2018-08-06 14:22:32 full backup started for directory /var/lib/vz/dump/dump (baseline backup #1) 2018-08-06 14:22:33 Aborting backup up after signal PIPE 2018-08-06 14:22:34 Got fatal error during xfer (aborted by signal=PIPE) <

My backup drive is a nfs drive which is mounted as /mnt/backuppc and topdir for backuppc is /mnt/backuppc/backuppc I am able to write into it with user backuppc and/or root.

I went through several documentations and here are what I have done for debugging.

ssh -l root domain whoami root

su
    su -s /bin/bash backuppc
        /usr/share/backuppc/bin/BackupPC_dump -v -f HOST

gives me this output

backuppc@backup3:/home/user$ /usr/share/backuppc/bin/BackupPC_dump -v -f HOST cmdSystemOrEval: about to system /bin/ping -c 1 HOST cmdSystemOrEval: finished: got output PING HOST (149.202.75.195) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from ns3013409.ip-149-202-75.eu (149.202.75.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=23.6 ms

--- HOST ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.654/23.654/23.654/0.000 ms

cmdSystemOrEval: about to system /bin/ping -c 1 HOST cmdSystemOrEval: finished: got output PING HOST (149.202.75.195) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from ns3013409.ip-149-202-75.eu (149.202.75.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=23.6 ms

--- HOST ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.602/23.602/23.602/0.000 ms

CheckHostAlive: returning 23.602 full backup started for directory /var/lib/vz/dump/dump (baseline backup #1) started full dump, share=/var/lib/vz/dump/dump Running: /usr/bin/ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -q -x -l root HOST /usr/bin/rsync --server --sender --protocol=29 --numeric-ids --perms --owner --group -D --links --hard-links --times --block-size=2048 --ignore-times . /var/lib/vz/dump/dump/ Xfer PIDs are now 2549 xferPids 2549 Got remote protocol 29 Negotiated protocol version 29 Remote[2]: skipping directory . Xfer PIDs are now 2549,2550 xferPids 2549,2550 Can't write 4 bytes to socket Read EOF: Tried again: got 0 bytes Child is aborting Done: 0 files, 0 bytes Got fatal error during xfer (aborted by signal=PIPE) Backup aborted by user signal Not saving this as a partial backup since it has fewer files than the prior one (got 0 and 0 files versus 1831) dump failed: aborted by signal=PIPE <

When I run the rsync command manually, the backup is started correctly:

rsync -av -e ssh root@HOST:/var/lib/vz/dump/dump /mnt/backuppc/backuppc/pc/pHOST/2<

Here below my HOST.pl file:
$Conf{RsyncShareName} = [
  '/etc',
  '/var/lib/vz/dump/dump'
];
$Conf{RsyncClientCmd} = '$sshPath -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -q -x -l root $host $rsyncPath $argList+';
$Conf{RsyncArgs} = [
  '--protocol=29',
  '--numeric-ids',
  '--perms',
  '--owner',
  '--group',
  '-D',
  '--links',
  '--hard-links',
  '--times',
  '--block-size=2048'
];
$Conf{ClientTimeout} = 72000;
$Conf{PingMaxMsec} = 50;
$Conf{XferMethod} = 'rsync';
$Conf{RsyncClientPath} = '/usr/bin/rsync';

I don't understand why it could log into the hosts to backup correctly and aborting immediatly after the backup start.

Can someone help me find a way out of this issue as I think I have done all the google search that could be done on this error message. Thanks a lot.

ps: Apologies for the formatting of this post, this is my first thread here and not yet familar with the syntax.

Comment: Please lookup formatting help and format your question, as it is, it is almost unreadable. You should have seen this in the preview before you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, I deleted a defautl rsync ssh arg : --recursive which is mandatory so my host.pl is just like this $Conf{RsyncShareName} = [ '/etc', '/var/lib/mysql', '/var/mysql' ]; $Conf{RsyncClientCmd} = '$sshPath -q -x -l root $host $rsyncPath $argList+'; $Conf{RsyncArgs} = [ '--numeric-ids', '--perms', '--owner', '--group', '-D', '--links', '--hard-links', '--times', '--block-size=2048', '--recursive' ]; –

Hope this will helps someone in the future...